# making line legends for geom_density in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

with ggplot2, I make the following density plot:

```
ggplot(iris) + geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species))
```

The colour legend (for each Species value) appears as a box with a line through it, but the density plotted is a line. Is there a way to make the legend appear as just a colored line for each entry of Species, rather than a box with a line through it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One possibility is to use `stat_density()` with `geom="line"`. Only in this case there will be only upper lines.

```
  ggplot(iris)+
    stat_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),
                     geom="line",position="identity")
```

If you need also the whole area (all lines) then you can combine `geom_density()` with `show_guide=FALSE` (to remove legend) and `stat_density()` than will add legend just with horizontal lines.

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),show_guide=FALSE)+
  stat_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),
                  geom="line",position="identity")
```

[image]

Comment: The second solution is what I'm looking for - but doesn't this double plot the density lines on top of each other, so that they look thicker?

Comment: Yes, this plots them twice. This is just workaround for this problem.

Comment: is there no way to just change the legend without plotting twice?

Comment: @user248237dfsf At least I didn't found solution just with changing legend (although I tried several ways).

Comment: I see. Could you just point to an example of how would change the legend manually to do this? Assuming you use geom_density

Comment: Idea is to use functions guides() and argument override.aes= to change legend entries. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320148/ggplot2-draw-dashed-lines-of-same-colour-as-solid-lines-belonging-to-different-g) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961986/combine-fill-and-colour-legends-when-using-expression-labels) are some examples with other geoms

Answer (score 10):

The `show_guide` function used in the answer by @liesb is deprecated under ggplot 3.0.0; it has been changed to `show.legend`:

```
ggplot(iris) + 
geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),show.legend=FALSE) +
stat_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),
             geom="line",position="identity", size = 0) + 
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=1)))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  stat_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),
                  geom="line",position="identity")
```

Will do want you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can get around plotting the lines twice by

```
ggplot(iris) + 
geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),show_guide=FALSE) +
stat_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species),
             geom="line",position="identity", size = 0) + 
guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes=list(size=1)))
```

ps: sorry for not commenting on the obviously correct answer -- lack of rep issues :)

pps: I realise the thread is quite old but it helped me today, so it might help someone else sometime...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fill the boxes in the legend, add `fill` in geom_density, but use `alpha=0` and override the legend to `alpha=1`. Like this:

```
ggplot(iris) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=Sepal.Width, colour=Species, fill = Species), alpha = 0) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```